# How to get x,y coordinates using python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have detected the corners (red dots in the image) of this image using below algorithm (cornerHarris). Now I want to get the coordinates of that points. How can I do that?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

filename = 'Square.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(filename)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gray = np.float32(gray)
dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray,2,3,0.04)

#result is dilated for marking the corners, not important
dst = cv2.dilate(dst,None)

# Threshold for an optimal value, it may vary depending on the image.
img[dst>0.01*dst.max()]=[0,0,255]

cv2.imshow('dst',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imwrite('CornerSquare.jpg',img)
```

[image]

Comment: I am not too familiar with python or Harris Comer, but scanning through your code I don't see any code that refers to that you have detected the red dots

Comment: this code is working! and the image I upload is what I got by running this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
coord = np.where(np.all(img == (0, 0, 255), axis=-1))
print zip(coord[0], coord[1])
```

Comment: where should I place this code in my code? after I color the point in red or somewhere else

Comment: @ManojAmarasekera The code above simply calculates the coordinates of each red dot in you picture. Therefore, it needs to be placed after `img[dst>0.01*dst.max()]=[0,0,255]`. If you are using python3 you may need to adjust the `zip` line as python3 will return a pointer instead of a list.

Comment: your answer is what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: sir, I have some issues to clarify from you... IDK whether this is right or wrong can i have an email address or something to contact you sir?