# How to get the x and y coordinate from an (x,y) point in Python?

Tags: python

I have a string variable which is a point, such as m="(2, 5)" or m="(-6, 7)". I want to extract the x coordinate and y coordinate and store them in different variables. Could someone provide some code in Python for how I could do this? Thanks!

Comment: you can find the answer for your question here : [how-to-get-x-y-coordinates-using-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36372068/how-to-get-x-y-coordinates-using-python)

Comment: I looked at that post but I don't see where my question is answered. Could u show where exactly the code is that would answer my question? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

maybe that help you

```
m = "(7, 5)"
x, y = m.strip('()').split(',')
print(x) # 7
print(y) # 5
```

with variables :

```
m = "(7, 5)"
x, y = m.strip('()').split(',')

var1 = x
var2 = y

print(var1)
print(var2)
```

Comment: One take is that this will return strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ast` library. As explained in this answer for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/1894296/7509907

In your case you could do something like this:

```
import ast

m="(-2, 5.5)"
x, y = ast.literal_eval(m)

print(x, type(x))
print(y, type(y))
```

Output:

```
-2 <class 'int'>
5.5 <class 'float'>
```

This will also convert your values to integers/floats when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Isolate the numbers from string.

```
m = "(2, 5)"
x, y = m.strip('()').split(',')
x, y

('2', ' 5')
```

Convert string numbers to float to allow them to be used mathematically. Can't do math with strings.

```
x, y = float(x), float(y)
x, y

(2.0, 5.0)
```

Answer (score -2):

Weird, but ok.

```
def coords(m):
  for i in range(2, len(m) - 2):
    if m[i] == ',':
      return m[1:i],m[(i+1),(len(m)-1)]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I seem to get a syntax error.

Comment: Yeah, my python is rusty.  I assume it's in the for loop range.  Instead try:
for i in range(2, len(m) - 2):

Comment: Yeah, I did a quick python syntax review and what I edited it to should be more accurate.